# Unclassifiable statement error of Logical Type - Fortran

Tags: fortran

```
program test
logical :: check
check = 2 < 3 < 5
print *, check
end program test
```

When trying to compile, it will give this error:

> Error(s): source_file.f:5:0:
>
> check = 2 < 3 < 5  1 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

where is the problem?

you can test it online here: https://rextester.com/l/fortran_online_compiler

Comment: Maybe the type should read LOGICAL?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner no it is not related to upper case or lower case

Comment: It's not a valid form of a logical expression in Fortran - what are you trying to do? I can't work it out from here. And Fortran is case insensitive

Comment: I guess OP wants something like `check = 2 < 3 .and. 3 < 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that 2 is less then 3 and 3 is less then 5 then you really need two comparisons and one Boolean operator

```
check = (2 < 3) .and. (3 < 5)
```